# Is a bad practice bundle a whole express application to one file?

Tags: typescript, express, esbuild

Normally I use `tsc` to compile the typescript code to production.

Recently I am using `esbuild` for fastest builds, I discover that it allows you to compile all the application to a single file, via:

```bash
esbuild index.ts --outfile=index.js --bundle --minifiy --platform=node
```

This results in an `index.js` of more than 2 Megabytes.

Can this be considered a bad practice? From what I understand there is no problem with this method:

1. Saves space on the server of a massive `node_modules` folder
2. It is easier to move and test
3. It is much faster

Comment: It's fine, yeah.

Comment: I can think of only one thing where it can somewhat create an issue, in case there are some issues and exceptions on production usually the exception will print the line number in an individual file (although it will be in TSC compiled files but still it's okay in the individual files). Having one chunk of this file will make this difficult. I hope I am making some sense here

Comment: @DhruvPal Good point!